# Pandas dividing distance by timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timedelta

I am working in a dataframe in Pandas and I need to get the speed of an identifier by dividing the calculated distance by time difference for each point in each identifier.

I have tried dividing the two columns but get an error saying I can't do that division and switching the two leads to incorrect values.

Here is the df:

```python
 identifier  name     num_pts   time_diff                distance
0 AL011851  UNNAMED   5        00:00:00                  NaN
1 AL011851  UNNAMED   5        06:00:00                 65.927879
2 AL011851  UNNAMED   5        06:00:00                 67.758830
3 AL011851  UNNAMED   5        06:00:00                 58.817671
4 AL011851  UNNAMED   5        -1 days +06:00:00        56.385678
5 AL021851  UNNAMED   1        00:00:00                 NaN
6 AL031851  UNNAMED   1        00:00:00                 NaN
```

I am trying to put the speed in a new column in the dataframe by dividing the distance by time difference

Comment: What is the unit for distance?

Comment: unit for distance is kilometers

Comment: no problem thank you as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the total seconds for the timedelta column, convert to hours, and divide:

```
time = pd.to_timedelta(df.time_diff, errors='coerce').dt.total_seconds() / 3600
# If already timedelta, use
# time = df.time_diff.dt.total_seconds() / 3600
df['distance'] / time

0          NaN
1    10.987980
2    11.293138
3     9.802945
4    -3.132538
5          NaN
6          NaN
dtype: float64
```